# How to prevent the encrypted (AES) data from being tampered with?

Tags: c#, aes

I want to encrypt the data (AES) after saving it to the database and decrypt it when reading. How can I prevent data from being tampered with in the database? My algorithm is improved from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx.

I have tested, in the encrypted ciphertext casually add "a", decryption will throw an exception(The padding is invalid and is not removed), add any charactor,will throw an exception?there is no such possibility: do not throw an exception, you can decrypt, but the result is not the original data

```
string original = "getABEDKK";
string password = "123456kfjsEYR+*j";
string cipherText = Encrypt(original, password);
MessageBox.Show("After encrypt:"+cipherText);

string plainText = Decrypt("a"+cipherText, password);
MessageBox.Show("After decrypt:" + plainText);
```

Comment: Have you considered about using checksum?

Comment: Are you saying that if you tampered with the data, you got an exception when decrypting? Isn't that what you want then?

Comment: If you want to outright prevent the tampering in the first place, detecting that it has happened when you decrypt is too late then you need to lock down the storage, simple as that.

Comment: Those kinds of encryption/decryption algorithms do not really work like that. If something has changed then it will most likely throw an exception because it literally cannot be decrypted. The only thing I can think of that would behave in the way you want is a simple XOR encryption and that is not the most secure..

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen-"If you want to outright prevent the tampering in the first place, detecting that it has happened when you decrypt is too late then you need to lock down the storage, simple as that."     Indeed. How do I lock storage?

Comment: Prevent unauthorized access to the database?

Comment: Yes.I plan to strengthen server management.

Comment: This is what a [Message Authentication Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac(v=vs.110).aspx) is for

Comment: If  you are expecting the data in the database to be changed by any other mean than your application then that is the first thing you need to fix. You definitely do not want any changes to happen in database via back door in production environment. If you can protect your database from unauthorized access you don't need to worry about encrypting the data.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya---Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add something like a checksum or validation field.  Then add a layer to the encryption that decrypts the data, checks the validation and throws an exception if the validation field is not correct.

Comment: Adding anything on my cipherText,will throw exception,such as my code above?

Comment: You don't understand.  You add the checksum or validation to the text **before** you encrypt it.  Usually that validation field will be some function of the actual content you want to encrypt.  Then when you decrypt, you decrypt the encrypted text, then the decrypted text should contain your validation field, formatted properly, and it should still match what you get from applying the function that generated it in the first place.